# The City of '17

Tags: knowledge, video-games, sports

Excited, you turn on your TV, to find out who is the 'City of '17'. The screen shows the show presenter:

---

*'Every year, a city or cities is or are named as the city of that year.*

*Before announcing this year's winner, let's take a look at some of the honoured previous winners...*

> 2002 - London
>   2006 - Manchester and Barcelona
>   2010 - Manchester and London, London receiving it twice
>   2014 - Barcelona and Madrid
>   2015 - London and Barcelona
>   2016 - Liverpool and Barcelona
>   2017 - ***??????***

*And now to present the winner of the City of '17. 


The winner is...'*

---

At this point, the connection is typically cut off, as your house has a power cut and you are left fuming in the darkness.

**Can you work out who won the "City of '17"?**

Hint:

> The tags

Comment: Seems like it could be related to prime factorization, but I've no idea how.

Comment: @A.Mirabeau, note there is no [tag:mathematics] tag - so wrong track

Comment: Something to do with sport?

Comment: I would go with London and Barcelona just based on statistical probability

Comment: @yitzih, unfotunately not

Comment: @randal'thor, very related to sport

Comment: Must be fifa 17 then...

Comment: @Sid, answer, answer, answer!

Comment: Am i the only one who thought about Half-Life?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing,

> Must be Dortmund since the cover of fifa 17  contain player of the club. [Marco Reus of Dortmund on the cover of Fifa 17](http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2016/0721/r105846_1296x729_16-9.jpg&w=738&site=espnfc).

**(OP Edit)**:

Here are the covers for the mentioned:

> 2002 - Thierry Henry - Arsenal - London - https://i.stack.imgur.com/phPhT.jpg
> 2006 - Rooney,  Ronaldinho - Manchester United, Barcelona - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHluM.jpg
> 2010 - Rooney, Walcott, Lampard - Man Utd, Arsenal, Chelsea - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ry88.jpg
> 2014 - Messi, Bale - Barcelona, Real Madrid - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLQRu.jpg
> 2015 - Hazard, Messi - Chelsea (London), Barcelona - https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBeHa.jpg
> 2016 - Henderson, Messi - Liverpool, Barcelona - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ywfs.jpg

And then the 2017 cover:

> 2017 - Marco Reus - Borussia Dortmund - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UB39.jpg

Comment: I was actually only looking for [dortmund](http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2016/0721/r105846_1296x729_16-9.jpg&w=738&site=espnfc) but this is still correct

Answer (score -1):

According to Google -

> La clasico competition (soccer - football in Europe) Real Madrid and Barcelona for the 2017 time frame.

Comment: Could you edit this answer to add in an explanation as to why you think it is correct? Thanks!

Comment: how does 2002 fit in?

Comment: If you mean "[el clásico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Cl%C3%A1sico)", that's just an inofficial name given to football matches between Real Madrid and FC Barcelona. These occur at least twice every season and often there are other encounters in national and Euroean cup ties.

Comment: Sorry completely incorrect. Except for the soccer part...